# Vertically align sans-serif font precisely at changing font-size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

My problem is an extension to the problem I stated already in an earlier problem, see here [Vertically align sans-serif font precisely using jquery/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444495/vertically-align-sans-serif-font-precisely-using-jquery-css).

In a nutshell: I want to align two divs with text, one above the other, in order to always align the beginning of the A (basically the lower left point of the A) with the H (the left vertical line of the H)? An idea of what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The top div has a varying font-size and I want to align the lower div according to the font. The reason is that I scale my font size according to the window size.

A [demo on jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksuTQ/6/) .

HTML

```
<div id="Hideheader" class="Header" style="position: absolute;font-size:40pt;padding:0px;visibility: hidden;width:auto;height:auto;">HEADER</div>
<div id="header" class="Header">HEADER</div>
<div id="menubar" class="menubar">
    <div class="menubutton_left"><a href="#" id="WorkButton">A</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menubutton_middle"><a href="#" id="AboutButton">B</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menubutton_right"><a href="#" id="ContactButton">C</a>
    </div>  <span class="stretch"></span>

</div>
```

CSS

```
div.Header {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-align:justify;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div.menubar {
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
div.menubutton_left, div.menubutton_middle, div.menubutton_right {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    width:60px;
}
div.menubutton_left {
    margin-left:12px;
}
div.menubutton_middle {
    text-align: center;
}
div.menubutton_right {
    text-align: right;
}
.stretch {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

JSCRIPT

```
resizeHead("#Hideheader", "#header");

$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeHead("#Hideheader", "#header");
});

function resizeHead(p1, p2) {
    var fontsize = parseFloat($(p1).css("font-size"));
    var spacing = parseFloat($(p1).css("letter-spacing"));
    var initWidth = $(p1).width();
    initWidth = initWidth - spacing;
    var outWidth = $(p2).width();

    var s = outWidth / initWidth;
    s = fontsize * s;
    $(p2).css({
        "font-size": s
    });
}
```

Try resizing your browser window. I becomes especially apparent for smaller end of font sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I really understand your question.. But, due to your fiddle, I think I see what you want. I would recomend:

**1:** Don't use JS to set increase font-size. You can use variable size units like `vw`, `vh` or `vmin`. They change it's size according to parent container, like: `font-size: 20vw`.

It is a LOT lighter than having javascript to trigger on every window resize.

**2:** You have set a fixed width to your divs, so whenever it becomes smaller than `60px` your layout will break. Remove it. You can set a dynamically calculated width, like: `width: calc(100% / 3)`, so all your three divs will be placed accordingly.

**3:** You have set a `margin-left` on your first div that also breaks your layout. Instead, add the margin to the `<a>` tag inside the div:

```
div.menubutton_left a {
    margin-left:12px;
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle, with all the changes (and no js \o/): http://jsfiddle.net/ksuTQ/7/

Comment: Wow, that's some great advice, thanks! Would you also happen to know a solution in order to always align the beginning of the A (basically the lower left point of the A) with the H (the left vertical line of the H)? I hope I'm not too confusing with my question. And I don' have enough reputation to upvote your answer :|

Comment: No problem at all... Well, first, I've set your header to `text-align: center`, so change it back to `text-align: left`. Now, to align the way you want, maybe you can set your <a> `margin-left` to something percentual. See if it helps someway: http://jsfiddle.net/ksuTQ/8/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've solved this issue with my own applications before, but by sloppy means. You might not want to do things this way, but I'll share it anyway. I do really like the post by @LcSalazar, but I've found in the past that I sometimes have trouble configuring the rest of my page once I've added elements with relative positioning, but it appears that your doing that anyway. Try the answer by @LcSalazar first, then if you really want to, try this. I also suggest trying to use elements such as span instead of div, but that might change your entire project.

The biggest issue is that, in HTML, there really is no good means of collecting TextMetrics, as that is what you are asking for. Canvas elements have TextMetrics, but they only provide width.

```
var myCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var myContext = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

var myText = "I'm getting measured by canvas calls!";

var textMetrics = myContext.measureText(myText);

var textWidth = textMetrics.width;
```

Unfortunately, what your looking for is height.
This is what I've done in the past.

```
var hiddenDiv =  document.createElement('div');
hiddenDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
hiddenDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
hiddenDiv.style.top = '0px';
hiddenDiv.style.left = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(hiddenDiv);

var myText = "I'm getting measured by a sloppy div";

function getTextHeight(text, font)
{
   hiddenDiv.style.font = font;
   hiddenDiv.innerHTML = text;

   return hiddenDiv.clientHeight;
}

var myFont = 'normal 13px Verdana';

var textHeight = getTextHeight(myText, myFont);
```

You can then use the text height to do any sort of resizing or relative positioning that you wanted to do. Sorry I didn't try to incorporate it into your project myself, I just wanted to show you a means of collecting text height without writing a massive block of code. Make sure that you set the font of the div before you measure it! Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, I'm not looking not for height, but the offset to the beginning of the division, an idea of what i'm trying to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/xyn5UDZ.png

Comment: Ooh, now I understand what you saying. Sounds kinda tricky, but I think that this could be accomplished using CSS. Try setting margin and padding to 0. I'm not exactly sure if this will do what you want it too, I've never actually tried to do that before.